# out of vs from - one out of many, one from many

Tags: prepositions

1. Is there a subtle difference between *one out of many* and *one from many*?
2. Would you prefer one to the other?
3. Is this the only case where *out of* and *from* are exchangeable?
4. Could one say: *this is made from one piece* and *this is made out of one piece*?
5. And what about *this is made out of wood* and *this is made from wood*?
6. I guess I could drop the *out* in the first one, couldn't I?
7. And *this building is built out of stone* vs *this building is built from stone*?

Comment: Please stick to one question per question, or at most a couple of closely related ones.

Comment: All questions are about the meaning of *out of* and *from*.

Comment: Yes, they're quite closely related. But there are a lot more than a couple of them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: ok

Answer (score 2):

"One out of many" implies "One randomly chosen out of many similar ones."

"Choose one from many" has a similar meaning.

"Out of many, one" means that "Many were combined, to make one."  (It is a translation of the Latin phrase *e pluribus unum*, which is the motto of the United States of America.  Under the doctrine of *dual sovereignty*, the many continued to exist in parallel with the new federal government.)

"One from many" is ambiguous.  It could mean "One chosen from many", or "Out of many, one."

The original poster's fourth through seventh questions can be answered affirmatively.